# How to allow multiple connections to Dancer2

Tags: perl, dancer

I am using Perl Dancer2 as the RESTful service framework with the basic setting (using command

> dancer2 -a MyWeb::App

to generate template files and add "get" routes in the auto-generated MyWeb-App/lib/MyWeb/App.pm file). Recently I found out that when one request needs a long period of time to finish, the server is locked to only serve that request. For example

```
get '/' => sub {# simple request to redirect to a static page
    template 'index'; #template directive Templates all go into the views/
};
get '/compute' => sub{
    for (my $i=0;$i<1000000;$i++){
         wait(1000);  #simulate long computation time 
    }
    return "Done!";
};
```

When firstly in one tab `http://myhost.com/compute` is entered, in another tab the link `http://myhost.com/` won't display anything until the previous /compute route finishes, which seems to me that only one connection is allowed at a time. The question is how to set up the Dancer2 server to allow multiple connections, i.e. the two tabs mentioned above can be run at the same time?

Many thanks!

Comment: See [Dancer::Deployment](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Dancer/lib/Dancer/Deployment.pod) and [Dancer2::Manual::Deployment](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Dancer2/lib/Dancer2/Manual/Deployment.pod).

Comment: Many thanks for the links which I failed to find on the perldancer website

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are you deploying your Dancer2 app? If you're using `plackup`, then you should realise that the default server that `plackup` uses only supports a single connection. But you can use the `-s` option to change to something like [Starman](https://metacpan.org/release/Starman), which supports multiple connections. See [Dancer2::Manual::Deployment](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Manual::Deployment) for more details.

If that's not the case, then you need to tell us more about your application. Is it possible that requests are blocking because they all need access to some shared resource?